# Ajax in JQuery submitting form twice

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

EDIT: SOLVED

I know that this is a pretty common issue, but I've looked through the answers- preventDefault and stopImmediatePropagation don't seem to be working, so I figured I'd post my code. Problem is the title of this question- I have a form that I use Ajax to submit so that the page doesn't reload. It seems that the page does not in fact reload and everything goes well, but if I leave the browser on the page after submitting the post for a little while, it goes through again. Here's my code-

html form:

```
<form action="" id="ask" name='<%= pathName %>' method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
  <p>Ask an Expert</p>
  <p style="display: none;" id="error">Please enter valid information</p>

  <label>Email  
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
  </label>
  <label>Question
    <textarea name="question" rows="4" id="question"></textarea>
  </label>
  <input value="<%= email %>" name="expEmail" style="display:none">
  <input value="<%= title %>" name="subject" style="display:none">
  <input type="submit" class="button" value="Send" />
</form>
```

JQuery:

```
$("#ask").on('submit',function(e) {

    function validateEmail(email) {
        var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        return re.test(email);
    }

    if (validateEmail($('#email').val()) && ($('#question').val() !== '')) {
        document.getElementById('ask').style.display='none'
        document.getElementById('emailSent').style.display='initial'
    } else {
        document.getElementById('error').style.display='initial'
        return false;
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

    var path = 'http://localhost:3000/page/' + $('#ask').attr('name');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: path,
        data: $("#ask").serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            $("#form_output").html(data);
        }
    });

    return false;

});
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. To reiterate: the second submission is only if I stay on the page for a while. Thanks!

Comment: By the way: 1. use `<input type="email">`; 2. once you are using jquery, use `var $ask = $('#ask')`, `$ask.hide()`... ^^

Comment: The form isn't submitting with ajax at all, because you have errors, there is  no element with the ID `#emailSent`, so the javascript errors out on that line as `null` has no style property

Comment: @moonwave99- Any particular reason for that?

Comment: @adeneo- it is submitting- that part of my html was above the form, sorry, I forgot to include it. But I figured out my issue

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem, it was server side-> my server wasn't set up to actually send a response to the post request, and somehow (is this the typical way this is handled?) Ajax reacted by submitting the request a second time. Added the response to the server, and now it works as it should.